# Realm DB query sum of an attribute in dart

Tags: dart, realm

I've been trying to get the **sum** of a **type** from my **realmdb** using flutter dart. Unfortunately I am keep getting a runtime error:

*RealmException (RealmException: Error code: 36 . Message: Operation '.@sum' cannot apply to property 'type' because it is not a list)*

**This is my db schema:**

import 'package:realm/realm.dart';

```
part 'realmdb.g.dart';

@RealmModel()
class _Item {
  @MapTo('_id')
  @PrimaryKey()
  late ObjectId id;
  late String type;
  late String description;
  late double value;

  @MapTo('owner_id')
  late String ownerId;

  DateTime? date;
}
```

**Query:**

var groceries = realm.query('type.@sum.value =="Groceries"');

**This is a document from my collection:**

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6416459ebae4d0e8702d0e27"},"date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1679181214346"}},"description":"Bit Coin","owner_id":"6414e8ad4791938608072411","type":"Crypto","value":{"$numberDouble":"5987.0"}}
```

I also would like to fetch the sum from any type. Like "Groceries" sum = 365, or "Leisure" sum = 643 etc.

Even after reading the official Site from https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/realm-query-language/ by converting their example

```
"items.@sum.progressMinutes > 100" into 'value.@sum.type =="Groceries"' i
```

t still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I would really appreciate your help.

Many thanks in advance.

OlaSebi88

var groceries = realm.query('type.@sum.value =="Groceries"');

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported with the query capabilities of the Flutter SDK. You can always do it in pure dart though:

```
var groceries = realm.query<Item>('type == "Groceries"');
var groceriesSum = groceries.fold(0, (sum, item) => sum + item.value);
```

While this may seem like an expensive operation from a SQL point of view, it is not expensive with Realm as it will only read the values from the database, not the entire `Item` object.

Comment: Hi Nikola, thx for the fast response. Well my main goal is to fetch the sum of any type per month and pass this to a list.

Comment: final Map<String, double> typeToSum = {};
    liste.forEach((item) {
      if (item.date?.month == DateTime.now().month) {
        final totalValue = typeToSum[item.type] ?? 0.0;
        typeToSum[item.type] = totalValue + item.value;
      }
    });

Comment: If you import the collections package, this can be simplified to: `realm.all<Item>().groupFoldBy((item) => item.type, (double? sum, item) => sum ?? 0 + item.value)`.

Comment: Hi Nikola, that works perfectly splended. Do you also have a query, which fetches the same data according the chosen month?